# Как задать переменную через ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$.validator.addMethod("check_login", function(value, element){
$check = false ;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "check.php",
  dataType: "json",
  data: $('.form_reg').serialize(),
  success: function(data){
    $check = data;
  }
});
return $check;
}, "Простите этот логин занят!");
```

у меня переменная `$check` возвращает всегда `false` а при алерте в самой функции работает нормально

Comment: что значит через?

Comment: А что не так?Какие проблемы то возникли?

Comment: @ThisMan классические :) Автор сначала возвращает переменную, а потом ajax-вызов заканчивается и присваивает ей значение.